# Background notification not redirecting to specific page flutter app

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, awesome-notifications

I have using awesome notification, Firebase messaging is used for push notification and in foreground notification is `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` using this callback redirect the user to specific is working as expected

but when the app is closed and tap the background notification is not working and I have using this callback  when the  background notification received
`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);`
is only opens the main screen not redirecting

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 

  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
        id: int.parse(message.data["id"]),
        channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
        title: message.data["title"],
        body: message.data["body"],
       

        icon: "resource://drawable/ic_stat_onesignal_default"),
    actionButtons: [
      NotificationActionButton(
        key: 'MARK_DONE',
        label: 'Snooze',
        icon: "resource://drawable/ic_stat_onesignal_default",
        enabled: true,
      )
    ],
  );
 
}
```

and my response from firebase messaging is
`{id: 9352, body: body, title: title, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}`

```
   <application
        
        android:label="example"
       
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            <meta-data
                 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                    android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
      BuildContext context, ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    ActionData actionData = ActionData(id: receivedAction.id.toString());
   
    if (receivedAction.channelKey == 'high_importance_channel') {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '${receivedAction.channelKey}');
    }

   Myapp.navigatorKey.currentState
        ?.pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Home(
                  data: receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed,
                )));
 
    if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == "") {
      print("appointment");
      Myapp.navigatorKey.currentState
          ?.pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>Secondscreen
      ));
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use `onActionReceivedMethod`?

Comment: In runApp(MyApp()) , i have used in the MyApp() statefulwidget inside the initstate AwesomeNotifications().setListeners()